# How to align csv file values into listview columns

Tags: c#

how do align the values from the csv file into my listview control... 
the problem in the code I used is that every csv values are added in the first column only...

this is my sample listview output:
[image]

the first "1234" needs to be aligned with "asd" but on the second column "p"

then the second "1234" needs to be aligned with "dfg" but on the second column "p"

### The correct display needs to be like this:

### u         |     p

```
   asd   |    1234

   dfg   |   1234
```

The "|" symbol represents only a border in the listview control between the 2 values... sorry for the misunderstanding..

Here is the code that I have constructed so far...

```
try
{

    string delimiter = ",";
    string tablename = "medTable";
    DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
    openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV Files (*.csv)|*.csv|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;
    if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {


        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to import the data from \n " + openFileDialog1.FileName + "?", "Are you sure?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename);
            string csv = File.ReadAllText(openFileDialog1.FileName);


            sr.Close();


            String[] strArray = csv.Split(new char[] { ',' });
            foreach (string strValue in strArray)
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(strValue);
            }

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }

}

catch (Exception ek)
{

}
```

I know there are a lot of gurus here who are very helpful ... 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to create a `SubItem` for the second value, right? Make sure the `ListView` has two `Columns` and is in `Details` view.

```
listView1.View = View.Details;
listView1.Columns.Add("header1");
listView1.Columns.Add("header2");
```

Although I prefer the designer to do that.. Now you can fill it:

```
using System.IO;
//..
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var parts = line.Split(',');
    ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(parts[0]);
    lvi.SubItems.Add(parts[1]);
    listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
}
```

You may want to add error checking before accessing the parts array!

A note on using the `SubItems` collection: When you later access it the `SubItem[1]` is the 2nd column and `SubItem[0]` is the first column, which you have actually added as the `Item`!

If you simply wanted the two values be concatenated, you would have changed my code to this:

```
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
foreach (string line in lines)
{
    var parts = line.Split(',');
    listView1.Items.Add(parts[0] + "  -  " + parts[1]);
}
```

Comment: yes.. to insert the second value to the next column... I've updated my question with an image attached to it...

Comment: Let's say for example i added another column named "w" in the listview control... i want to insert the two values in the "p" and "w" columns do i just simply change the array number in the parts array? or not?

Comment: What did you ask? There is one subitem for eacj column. the first one (index 0) is created by adding the item itself. all other you must add to the item.

Comment: I see, I'll experiment with the codes you've provided. Thank you for answering. . .

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace the foreach statement with this block

```
int i = 0;
string val = string.Empty;
foreach (string strValue in strArray)
{
    val += strValue + "  ";
    i++;
    if (i == 2)
    {
        listView1.Items.Add(val);
        i = 0;
        val = string.Empty;
    }

}
```

i hope this help you

**EDIT**
To add the items in 2 columns as displayed in picture you already posted 
please use this and i hope it works fine

```
 int i = 0;
 ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem();
 foreach (string strValue in strArray)
 {
    i++;
    if (i == 1)
    {
       item = new ListViewItem();
       item.Text = strValue;
    }
    if (i == 2)
    {
        item.SubItems.Add(strValue);
        listView1.Items.Add(item);
        i = 0;
    }
 }
```

Comment: umm... the "|" symbol is just a visual representation that serves as border between the 2 values... sorry about that ... let me edit that one above ... thanks for answering by the way.